# ERC 1155 batch minting issue solidity and nodejs

Tags: solidity, hardhat, polygon, erc-1155

here is the function for my batch minting, when I test this function on my Js file i get an error:

````
function batchMint(
        address to,
        uint256[] calldata amounts,
        uint256[] calldata tokenId,
        Category[] calldata categories
    ) external onlyMod {
        require(amounts.length == categories.length, "INVALID_ARGUMENTS");
        for (uint256 i; i < categories.length; i += 1) _safeMint(to, amounts[i], categories[i], tokenId[i]);```

I get this error when I run this function

Error: missing argument: passed to contract (count=3, expectedCount=4, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.2)


Nodejs code I run it with: I have passed both Three and Four data into the array, but it still doesnt work

```const batchMint = await Read.batchMint(userWallet.address, [30, 20, 70, 20], [1, 2, 3, 4] [4, 3, 2, 1])
    batchMint.wait();
    console.log(batchMint);```
````

Comment: you miss a commata here  [1, 2, 3, 4] [4, 3, 2, 1])

Comment: @ikijong I got this error, cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit